# Running scripts asynchronously in Azure DevOps

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, azure-devops, aws-sam

I am implementing a pipeline where I want to deploy a lambda to SAM and then be able to hit the endpoint that was started, the problem is that when the pipeline runs the **sam start local-api** it succeeds but keeps waiting forever:

This is the steps that creates the YAML to run SAM:

```
  - script: |
      yarn local
      yarn sam:dev-api
    displayName: "SAM Deployment"
    workingDirectory: api-generator/helloworld-api
```

And here you can see how it gets stucked waiting for the ednpoint to be hit of pressing ctrl + c:

[image]

Is there a way in which I can run the **sam start** command and the continue the pipeline to test the endpoint (kind of a sam start non-blocking run)? or a tool recommended to kind of run a virtual bash that can run several instances at the same time in Azure DevOps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could look into adding a condition of "always()"

Comment: Hi Diego, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you can set a limit to end 'deployment part' in time and do other automation after that. An example:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: A
  timeoutInMinutes: 1 #Use this to end the deployment part, set the value based on your situation.
  displayName: Deployment
  steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "A"
      vi README.md
      #The deployment logic here, and stuck in this place.

- job: B
  continueOnError: true
  condition: always() #Use this to start the test step
  dependsOn: A
  displayName: Test
  steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "B"
      #The test logic here.
```

Comment: Hi Bowman, sorry for the delay, we tried your suggested approach but we have limitations to run parallel agents in Azure, so we rather took a simpler approach, in one of the scripts we did this:

  - script: |
      sh -c 'yarn local && yarn sam:dev-api' &
    displayName: "SAM Deployment"
    workingDirectory: my-api

The & at the end makes the command run but disconnects the stdout so the pipeline sees the script as finished and continues with the next one, so with this the SAM service has active an endpoint that later we test with CURL. Thanks a lot for the help!